# Application_Error is not redirecting to Error Page from Global.asax when exception "Maximum request length exceeded" is raised

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, file-upload, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010/ASP.NET/C-Sharp website.

I basically had an ASP.NET FileUpload control, for which I needed to cater the exception thrown for the following message:-
Maximum request length exceeded.

The maximum file size setting is set in the web.config as follows:-

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
          <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="41943040"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

And

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="40960" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Usage Global.asax with validating file size in "Application_Error()", but it has not resolved my issue and it crashes at the Redirect when file size is greater and a redirect to Error Page is not working.

I want to find out that how can I accomplish my requirements, since I am stuck for this since a couple of days.
Kindly help me in this regards as early as possible.

I have used the following code, although it is now running the Application_Error() Code section, but the problem is that it is not redirecting to the About.aspx page.

```
  void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
        try
        {
            if (exc.Message.Contains("Maximum request length exceeded"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/About.aspx", false);                    
            }
            if (exc.InnerException.Message.Contains("Maximum request length exceeded"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/About.aspx", false);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```